# iframe .load event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reload an iframe like the following:

```
var frameObject = $('#myFrame');
var frameAsInDom = frameObject[0].contentWindow;
var currentLocation = frameAsInDom.location;
frameObject.attr('src', 'about:blank');
frameObject.contents().remove(); // This was a desperate statement!!
frameObject.attr('src', currentLocation).load(function(){
   alert('iframe reloaded');
});
```

The problem is the iframe's .load event is not getting triggered at all. I am not getting the **alert** inside the load call back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing the binding and triggering of the event,

See this code: http://jsfiddle.net/BvQuk/1/

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://google.com"></iframe><br/>
<input id="uxButton" type="button" value="Reload the frame" />
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var iFrame = $('#myFrame');

    iFrame.bind('load', function() { //binds the event
        alert('iFrame Reloaded');
    });

    $('#uxButton').click(function() {
        alert('onButtonClick OR onBeforeReload');
        var newSrc = iFrame.attr('src') + '?c=' + Math.random(); //force new URL
        iFrame.attr('src', newSrc); //changing the src triggers the load event
    });

});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what if i need different handlers for loading and reloading?

Comment: Loading and re-loading are (internally) the same, you request a web page to be loaded inside an iframe, what you can do is listen for the first load and fire an event there as well, if that is the case, let me know and I'll give you an example. Regards.

Comment: the problem is this...initially when i assign a src to the iframe a load event is attached... when i reassign the url to the iframe i attach a different load event handler... after reassigning the first handler fires and not the second..

Comment: You don't seem to understand how the event model works. The example is working as it should and the events are firing when and how they are supposed to.

If you want to perform a different action on first load, you can do so like this http://jsfiddle.net/BvQuk/2/.

Answer (score 0):

You have a JavaScript error: `currentLocation` is undefined. It's due to a typo on `var currenctLocation`.

## [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tRWq/)

Comment: sorry for the typo... Have made an update in the fiddle.. the load call back is not firing properly..http://jsfiddle.net/4tRWq/2/

Comment: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tRWq/3/) <-- look at the demo. and try to realize it based on the alerts made.

Comment: i guessed it.. but even if i unbind before binding again it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/4tRWq/4/

Comment: i don't understand the difference.. can u explain?

Comment: In my latest update, I bind `load-event` first, then change the source, was there still a unexpected behavior?

Comment: i noticed the change in the order.. i couldn't understand the difference the order event addition is going to make..yes..still the "reload" alert didn't fire..

Comment: You are mixing the binding and triggering of the event, see my simplified answer.